# Do we need to install RTC Build toolkit for running jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, ibm-jazz

I am using Jenkins for Continuous Integration and using Jazz for source control management(IBM Rational Team Concert ).

I want to check out the project  present in  Jazz source control  using Jenkins for that purpose i have installed IBM Rational Team Concert plugins in Jenkis.
But while configuring Build it ask for RTC Build toolkit ,Do we need to install this ? (The Server of Jazz is in different place not in same Machine)
Or is there any other way to do this ?

I tried to install 'Rational Team Concert - Build System Toolkit' it gives me error install-buildsystem.xml cannot be found .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the plugin website:

This plugin requires an installed Rational Team Concert Build Toolkit version 3.0.1.5 or newer.  See the [Installing the Build System Toolkit](https://jazz.net/help-dev/clm/topic/com.ibm.jazz.install.doc/topics/t_install_build_toolkit.html) help topic to learn how to install the build toolkit.

If you will be fetching workspaces that contain symbolic links, there is some additional symbolic link setup required.

You can find the download here:
https://jazz.net/downloads/rational-team-concert/milestones/6.0.2M3

You should select the client to istall and then use:
`Rational Team Concert - Build System Toolkit`